# Pandas read_csv parse_dates format "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" in column only parse date, missing time

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a statistic in csv files, some are huge file with thousands of lines.  the structure is:

```
"Result  :  Stat01"
"Save Time: 09/23/2019 19:01:27"

"User Name:admin"

"Total 1,365    Records"

"Start Time","Period","Messages Received","Messages Sent"
09/23/2019 01:30:00,5,114,57
09/23/2019 01:30:00,5,0,0
09/23/2019 01:30:00,5,47493,46911
09/23/2019 01:30:00,5,47772,46347
09/23/2019 01:30:00,5,0,0
09/23/2019 01:35:00,5,32990,34652
09/23/2019 01:35:00,5,142,63
09/23/2019 01:35:00,5,0,0
09/23/2019 01:35:00,5,47379,46297
09/23/2019 01:35:00,5,46324,45750
09/23/2019 01:35:00,5,0,0
09/23/2019 01:40:00,5,31974,33969
09/23/2019 01:40:00,5,114,57
09/23/2019 01:40:00,5,0,0
09/23/2019 01:40:00,5,44701,43845
09/23/2019 01:40:00,5,44903,43770
09/23/2019 01:40:00,5,0,0
09/23/2019 01:45:00,5,33531,35274
09/23/2019 01:45:00,5,126,63
09/23/2019 01:45:00,5,0,0
09/23/2019 01:45:00,5,45821,43960
09/23/2019 01:45:00,5,44988,45120
09/23/2019 01:45:00,5,0,0
09/23/2019 01:50:00,5,32544,33804
09/23/2019 01:50:00,5,112,56
09/23/2019 01:50:00,5,0,0
09/23/2019 01:50:00,5,45645,44609
09/23/2019 01:50:00,5,44878,44628
```

I tried to parse in pandas with **parse_dates** and **date_parser** but the result in pandas DataFrame is only date, it skip time.  the statistics have 5 minutes frequency and it requires time.
the code using is

```
mydateparser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
sta = pd.read_csv('Export.csv',skiprows=7,parse_dates=["Start Time"],date_parser= mydateparser)
sta.head()
```

the output does not have time:

```
Start Time  Period  Messages Received   Messages Sent
0   2019-09-23  5   46803   49665
1   2019-09-23  5   112 56
2   2019-09-23  5   0   0
3   2019-09-23  5   66647   65771
4   2019-09-23  5   67151   65191
```

thanks for your help

Comment: `sta = pd.read_csv('Export.csv',skiprows=7,parse_dates=["Start Time"])` works fine for me, ie without the `date_parser`.

Comment: @luigigi - Do you test original solution? For me working nice, so problem is not with parse to datetime, but missing times.

Comment: @jezrael tried it right now. its working fine for me, too

Comment: @dannisis - If test output by `sta = pd.read_csv('Export.csv',skiprows=7)` and `print (df['Start Time'])` there are times in all strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presentation for index was reduce to `%m-%d-%Y` however it has also time does not displayed.
thanks guys

[image: parse_date]

Answer (score -1):

"Period" seems to be the column containing time. You are parsing only "Start time". Parse both or combine both to one column.

Comment: Hi @Sharan_Sundar, **"Period"** is a integer with value 5, the **"Start time"** include the time like `09/23/2019 01:30:00`

Comment: Oh sorry my bad.